# Trigger event from a document object after delay

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im building an API with node and express running with a mongoDB for a mobile application, and basically it needs to trigger an event after a time period. For example:

A Request will come in for a driver who is needed in 30 minutes, I need the API to hang onto that record and after 25 minutes, query for the nearest driver and send them a notification with the details.

Does anyone know how to handle something like that on the server side?

Comment: I would use a cron job to do this. A quick google gave me some results: node-schedule and some blog posts.

Comment: Sounds like you need a job queue. Checkout https://github.com/Automattic/kue

Comment: @Bram `cron` is a poor choice for jobs you only want to execute once. Even with the more appropriate `at`, it will be tricky to make it call back into your application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some sort of background job. There are a few packages out there which do exactly what you want.

Essentially they push some metadata about the task you need to complete independently off your app, in the future, and when that time comes the data is used to process the task at hand.

Here are are a couple packages:

- [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue)
- [Bee Queue](https://github.com/LewisJEllis/bee-queue)

There's even a short [tutorial](https://medium.com/node-js-tips-tricks/implementing-a-job-queue-with-node-js-ffcfbc824b01#.94uvgi20q) that someone wrote which uses Kue.